# Unable to compile sharable .o files with g++

Tags: g++, program-entry-point, shared-libraries, build-error, fpic

When i compile with the following command:

> g++ -fPIC -o obj/buffer.o buffer.cpp

I get the following error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:
>   In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'

I am thought with the -fPIC flag, I didn't need a main function. I get this error with all of the cpp files. I do have a main.cpp that has the shared library functions in it. You can get the source code at the following:

> git clone https://github.com/nterry/39DLL-4-Linux.git

Any ideas? I know that I can use the ld binary to put all of the o files in the an so once they're done, I just need help in building them all into shareable .o files

Comment: I cannot find the source code

Comment: Uhhh, i'm able to clone the source anonymously. Are you using git? Did you copy and paste the command?

Comment: i think you have to use '-c' before filename. `g++ -fPIC -o obj/buffer.o -c buffer.cpp`

Comment: Just as an FYI, the new URL for the source code is git clone https://github.com/nterry/39DLL-4-Linux.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I answered my question. I added a -c to the command and it seems to have worked. Here is the command I used:

```
g++ -fPIC -c -o obj/list.o list.cpp
```

That is one of several cpp files, and all seemed to work.